# Adding Description to typescript .d.ts files

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm

We are trying to write a js library and we used .d.ts files to help with emits and stuff.
But the thing we can't figure out is how to add Descriptions to it .
What we have now :
[image]

What we want :

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [JSDoc syntax](https://jsdoc.app/about-getting-started.html), like so:

```
/**
 * Does something.
 */
declare function foo(name: string, age: number): string;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you should use [TSDoc](https://tsdoc.org/).

Here is an example, but you should obviously put more effort into your descriptions than this example:

```
/**
 * Log into the system.
 * 
 * @param config - The config object
 * @param userLogin - The user name to login with
 * @param userPassword - The password to login with
 * @param recaptchaResponse - The recaptcha response
 */
function login(config: any, userLogin: any, userPassword: any, recaptchaResponse: any): Promise<any>
{
    ////
}
```

One thing that will also help a lot, is taking advantage of TypeScript's type system. Try not to use `any` where possible. You should provide the actual types, then you will get better docs out of it.

You can also provide more than one type if that was the reason for just providing "any", using a Union Type like this:

```
(myParam: number | string)
```